# Changing character length of list columns in R

Tags: r

In R, I have a table with headers and each column has a different character lengths. i.e.

```
#   Level1   Level2   Level3
#1   a       d         e
#2   b       *blank*   f
#3   c       *blank*   *blank*
```

This is the code I read in to covert my df to a list.

```
df=read.csv("list.csv", header=TRUE, sep = ",")
lst1=list() 
for(i in 1:ncol(df)) {      
  lst1[[i]] <- df[ , i]    
}
names(lst1)=colnames(df)
print(lst1)
str(lst1)
```

However, I receive a list with the same character length. i.e.

```
List of 3
 $ level1: chr [1:3] "a" "b" "c"
 $ level2: chr [1:3] "d" "" ""
 $ level3: chr [1:3] "e" "f" ""
```

Is there a way to altering the list so the characters reflect the actual list length for each of the 3 object?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, it's going to remove all the `""`s in your elements of the list:

```
result <- lapply(lst1, function(x) x[nzchar(x)])
str(result)
List of 3
 $ Level1: chr [1:3] "a" "d" "e"
 $ Level2: chr [1:2] "b" "f"
 $ Level3: chr "c"
```

If it's what you need.

You may consider also to avoid a for loop to have `lst1`:

```
lst1 <- split(t(df), rownames(t(df)))
# Then apply the code above.
result <- lapply(lst1, function(x) x[nzchar(x)])
```

---

With data:

```
df <- structure(list(Level1 = c("a", "d", "e"), Level2 = c("b", "", 
"f"), Level3 = c("c", "", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: This worked for me. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the dataframe you can modify your code like this. It checks each element of the list and drops the blank and/or NA values

```
lst1=list() 
for(i in 1:ncol(df)) {      
    lst1[[i]] <- df[ , i]    
}

lst1 <- lapply(lst1, function(z){ z[!is.na(z) & z != ""]}) # this checks for blank and/or NA

names(lst1)=colnames(df)
print(lst1)
str(lst1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to your way you can subset `df` on both rows and columns.

```
lst1=list()
for(i in 1:ncol(df)) {      
  lst1[[i]] <- df[df[ , i] != '' , i]
}

names(lst1)=colnames(df)
```

---

**However, a much more concise answer is this neat one liner to handle it all**

```
map(df, function(x) x[nzchar(x)])
```

---

```
$Level1
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$Level2
[1] "d"

$Level3
[1] "e" "f"
```

---

```
structure(list(Level1 = c("a", "b", "c"), Level2 = c("d", "", 
""), Level3 = c("e", "f", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lapply(df, function(x) x[x != ""])

$Level1
[1] "a" "d" "e"

$Level2
[1] "b" "f"

$Level3
[1] "c"
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Level1 = c("a", "d", "e"), Level2 = c("b", "", 
"f"), Level3 = c("c", "", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```